# how can i search a string in sql database table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

this is my program

```
public partial class message : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AnonymiousSocialNetworkConnectionString"].ToString();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        txtuseremil.Text = Session["emid"].ToString();
    }
    protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        string value = txtmsg.Text;
        if (value.Contains(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select keyword from messageanalysis where keyword=@value"))// <--MY PROBLEM          
        {
            con.Open();
            lblStatus.Text = "Normal";   <-- I WANT TO DERIVE THIS VALUE FROM TABLE ACCORDING TO THE VALUE I GET FROM keyword
            Frdsclass.Text = "Just Friend";    <--- I WANT TO DERIVE THIS VALUE FROM TABLE ACCORDING TO THE VALUE I GET FROM keyword
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into messagetable(sendid,message,userid,emotional,friendsclassify) values (@snd,@msg,@usr,@emo,@frdcl)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@snd", txtsndmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", txtmsg.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", txtuseremil.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emo", lblStatus.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frdcl", Frdsclass.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

how can i search a word or sentence in database table?? is my method correct?? plz help if u have a solution

Comment: execute the first sql query with a `@value`.

Comment: A `string` cannot contain a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: you could use the [SelectQueryBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S) package over at codeproject. otherwise, write your own dynamic query.

Comment: Two points... 1) as Amit said, what is the value of @value ... 2) look into ExecuteScalar() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: actually i want to read a keyword from an input text and compare it with a column(keyword) in database and also get the corresponding data from other field names(emotion) and (friends classfier)

Comment: You may want to look into turning on full-text searching in Sql Server.  It's built to do this type of thing, especially if you have a large data set.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your question is not quite clear. If you want to search a substring in a varchar field you can do it with a like

SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourvarcharfield LIKE '%yoursearchstring%'

if you wanto look in different fields you can chain with ...or yourotherFild like '%yousearchstring%'

if you want to search those records that start with your searchstring the condition is

..like 'yoursearchstring%'

Comment: There is a table with three columns keyword,emotion and friend classifier i want to take a text input from textbox and search words of that textbox in keyword column..if a match is found i want to display the corresponding row values of emotion and friend classifier in lblstatus.text and frdsclass.text

Comment: what does the keyword column contain? words or sentences??

Comment: keyword column contains a specific word

Comment: you have to break the text in the textbox into an array or list of strings. Then you have to do the search with each member of the array/string. Be careful with short words like a or is if you search with a like search. That is no problem with an exact search

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetValue (string searchValue)
{
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString));
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     "select keyword from messageanalysis where value=@value")
  {
      cmd.AddParameter("@value",searchValue);
      var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();


      return (result == null)? null : result.ToString();     

  }
}
```

....

```
var keyword = GetValue(value);
if (keyword != null && value.Contains(keyword)){
```

....

You could do something like this.  I've separated your select statement into a different function.  This will look for your value that you pass in and return your keyword.  if it doesn't find it, the function returns null.  I then set it to check and see if the keyword is null (since null is not found) and if it finds the value to execute the conditional code.

Comment: can i send you screenshots of my database table and show you what i want from it??

Comment: I have to go into a meeting in a few but I'll see what I can do.  here is a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/104548/so-question-35629105?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**NOTE:ExecuteScalar()** will returns the first record of the resultset.

```
    public partial class message : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AnonymiousSocialNetworkConnectionString"].ToString();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            txtuseremil.Text = Session["emid"].ToString();
        }
        protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            string value = txtmsg.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select keyword from messageanalysis where keyword = @value")

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Keywordtextbox.text);
            cmd.Connection=con;
            con.Open();
            if (Keywordtextbox.text.Contains(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))         
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Normal";
                Frdsclass.Text = "Just Friend";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into messagetable(sendid,message,userid,emotional,friendsclassify) values (@snd,@msg,@usr,@emo,@frdcl)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@snd", txtsndmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", txtmsg.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", txtuseremil.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emo", lblStatus.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frdcl", Frdsclass.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: can i send screenshots of database table,my program and what i want from it  to anyone who can help me out please :(

Comment: @SaifInamdar what are you trying to do? you want to search keyword in messageanalysis table or anything else? explain your requirement little bit more

Comment: There is a table with three columns keyword,emotion and friend classifier i want to take a text input from textbox and search words of that textbox in keyword column..if a match is found i want to display the corresponding row values of emotion and friend classifier in place of lblstatus.text and frdsclass.text

Comment: `if (value.Contains(cmd.ExecuteScalar())) `  what's in the `value` variable in above code?

Comment: There is a table with three columns keyword,emotion and friend classifier i want to take a text input from textbox and search words of that textbox in keyword column..if a match is found i want to display the corresponding row values of emotion and friend classifier in  lblstatus.text and frdsclass.text –

Comment: it didnt worked   these are the two errors after i fixed some                                              Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments G:\Emotion ExP1\Facebook\message.aspx.cs 28 17 G:\Emotion ExP1\
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' G:\Emotion ExP1\Facebook\message.aspx.cs 28 38 G:\Emotion ExP1\

Answer (score 0):

if your textfield can contain more than one word you have to separate the words in the appropriate number of strings and then

select the records with a like saerch as shown in my previous answer

SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourvarcharfield LIKE '%string1%' or yourvarcharfield LIKE '%string2%' or ...

as the textfield can have various numbers of words you have to build your sqlcommand with a stringbuilder.

Comment: i am not really sure if your  txtmsg.Text contains 1 word or more words.

Comment: it will have more than one word..it will be a sentence.. in that sentence i need to search a keyword..

Comment: string value = txtmsg.Text;  string[] words = value.Split(' ');

Comment: You can break your sentence into a string array: string value = txtmsg.Text;  string[] words = value.Split(' '); then you can use string sqlcmd="select * from ... where keyword like '%"+string[1]+"%'" + " or keyword like '%"+string[2]+  or if you need exact match then: "select * from ... where keyword="+string[1]+" Or "+"keyword="+string[2]